# How can I resolve "\\PCNAME" to proper IP address with secondary IP enabled Windows 10 from "Run"?

Tags: windows-10, networking

My office local network has kind of old static IP configurations for all PCs and I am not allowed to make changes to many network configurations. There are many old PCs with IP 192.168.100.* and many new ones with 192.168.11.* . PC `\\SQL-SRVR-PC` has old IP(192.168.100.4 ). One of my new PC has a C# application running which connects to SQL server PC database with hard-coded PC name `\\SQL-SRVR-PC` which unfortunately I am not allowed to change. How I am trying to solve this, is I am assigning a secondary IP(old 192.168.100.* )  to new PCs that need to communicate with old PCs on the network and also giving them a primary IP (new 192.168.11.*
). With secondary IP everything is working fine. I can ping any pc with IP 192.168.100.* and 192.168.11.* . What I can't do is while I am starting `Run(Win+R)` and trying `\\SQL-SRVR-PC` from Run. It is not taking me to 192.168.100.4. But doing `\\192.168.100.4` working perfectly.
Is there any way I can keep my current IP settings and still be able to work `\\SQL-SRVR-PC` to resolve to proper machine?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.